# How do I use the java.scripting module?

Tags: java

I was looking for a solution to my problem and found a code that solves it. But the code used classes of the java.scripting module. I tried to import it, but got "The package javax.script is not accessible". Then I thought I needed to import the library. I almost didn't find JAR files with this library, and when I imported the ones I found, my program didn't see them. How do I make this code work?

```
 ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        try
        {
            imput.setText("" + engine.eval(imput.getText()));
        } 
        catch (ScriptException e1)
        {
            //...
        }
```

Comment: Which java version are you using? I think in later versions, the support for javascript has been removed due to no one wants to maintain it.

Comment: "package not accessible" is not the same as "package not found". I know that with [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) you have to modify the configuration in order to make certain packages accessible. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: if the project is modular, that is, it is using a `module-info.java` file to declare the module, you must add `java.scripting` to that `module-info.java` file (e.g. `requires java.scripting;`)

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer The [*Nashorn* JavaScript script engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) was [deprecated in Java 11](https://openjdk.org/jeps/335) and [removed in Java 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372). But [`javax.script.ScriptEngineManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.scripting/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html) remains as of Java 20.

Comment: Thank you all. Now I understand what the problems are.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted "module-info.java" and everything worked without downloading libraries.

Comment: So basically you put all your code into the [unnamed module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.5).